# Compare two columns if 1st cell matches with 2nd cell then

Tags: excel

My data is two different lists and they seem as following:

**List 1**

[image: List 1]

**List2**

[image: List 2]

in the attached pictures, are two lists, so I am trying to compare Date column in List 1 with Date column in List 2. If they match then multiply corresponding cells for (NG rate X Weight) and return results in Approved column.

**OBS** List 1 has always uniqe date while List 2 has several cells with same date. However, I want to multiply NG Rate for the corresponding date with Weight in List 2 which has the same date so the result will be as presented in pic of List 2.

I will appreciate your help

BR

I tried VLOOKUP but didn't work.

Comment: Pls. apply [Markdown](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/) formatting for sample data for easier handling.

Comment: Are those only dates or dates+times? `VLOOKUP()` should be working here? Could you explain.

Comment: I don't understand the Approved value for 2024-03-02 weight 50? 50 * 0,54% = 0,27

Comment: This is maybe a stupid remark, but in one cell, there is the value "0.81%", while in the other there is "0.81" (without percent). On my PC "0.81%" in fact means "0.0081" and not "0.81", so both values are not equal. how is it on your PC?

Answer (score 0):

This is a use case for `INDEX\MATCH`:

`=E2*INDEX($B$2:$B$5,MATCH(D2,$A$2:$A$5,0))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With VLOOKUP

`=VLOOKUP(D23,A$23:B$26,2,FALSE)*E23`

[image]